# Xamarin.Forms.UWP Numeric Keyboard only on soft keyboard

Tags: uwp, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I'm using Xamarin.Forms and want to have a numeric only keyboard for my users to login with a PIN.

I am able to use `Xamarin.Forms.Entry.Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric` to force a Numeric keyboard, and this works for iOS, Android and UWP Phones. However, when a user runs the same app on a UWP tablet, like a Microsoft Surface, it displays the full keyboard, which includes Characters along with Numbers.

I want a numeric keyboard to be the only input option to make data validation more simple and secure.

I know I can easily do validation as the text changes to ensure only numbers are present, but is there is a way to only display the number keypad in the soft keyboard for a `Xamarin.Forms.Entry` on the UWP platform?

Comment: On UWP desktop, even not only keyboard but user can enter non numeric value and it is accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I figured this one out myself and wanted to post the answer for future developers. This use case comes from having the soft keyboard displayed on UWP tablets because `Xamarin.Forms.Entry` utilizes the `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBox`. You can change the `InputScope` of the `TextBox` to change the keyboard in UWP as shown in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/6e5f55d7-24d6-47cc-b457-b6231ede2a71).

Of course I made the common mistake of not reading the documentation entirely, but rather jumping straight to what keyboards are available. In the docs there is an important line in the beginning:

> **Important**  The `InputScope` property on `PasswordBox` supports only the `Password` and `NumericPin values`. Any other value is ignored.

Oh snap! We're using a `TextBox` when we really want to use a `PasswordBox` for UWP. This can easily be achieved with a CustomRenderer and custom entry like below:

**Custom Entry:**

```
public class MyCustomPasswordNumericEntry: Xamarin.Forms.Entry
{
}
```

**Custom Renderer:**

```
public class PasswordBoxRenderer : ViewRenderer<Xamarin.Forms.Entry, Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.PasswordBox>
{
    Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.PasswordBox passwordBox = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.PasswordBox();
    Entry formsEntry;
    public PasswordBoxRenderer()
    {
        var scope = new InputScope();
        var name = new InputScopeName();

        name.NameValue = InputScopeNameValue.NumericPin;
        scope.Names.Add(name);

        passwordBox.InputScope = scope;
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null)
        {
            SetNativeControl(passwordBox);
        }

        if(e.NewElement != null)
        {
            formsEntry = e.NewElement as Entry;

            passwordBox.PasswordChanged += TextChanged;
            passwordBox.FocusEngaged += PasswordBox_FocusEngaged;
            passwordBox.FocusDisengaged += PasswordBox_FocusDisengaged;
        }

        if(e.OldElement != null)
        {
            passwordBox.PasswordChanged -= TextChanged;
        }
    }

    private void PasswordBox_FocusDisengaged(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Control sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.FocusDisengagedEventArgs args)
    {
        formsEntry.Unfocus();
    }

    private void PasswordBox_FocusEngaged(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Control sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.FocusEngagedEventArgs args)
    {
        formsEntry.Focus();
    }

    private void TextChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        formsEntry.Text = passwordBox.Password;
    }
}
```

And lastly make sure we just register the CustomRenderer:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.ExportRenderer(typeof(MyCustomPasswordNumericEntry), typeof(PasswordBox.UWP.PasswordBoxRenderer))]
```

Now our `MyCustomPasswordNumericEntry` will use a `Xamarin.Forms.Entry` on all platforms, but will use a `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.PasswordBox` on UWP. I also forwarded the basic events on the `Xamarin.Forms.Entry` to make everything work, but you would also need to have the `OnElementPropertyChanged()` method update the `PasswordBox` if there are changes coming from Validation on the Xamarin.Forms.Entry.TextChanged property.